# Understanding __getitem__ interaction with __len__

Tags: python

I am having trouble understanding something in this code:

```
normal_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

class CustomSequence():
    def __len__(self):
        return 5
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return "x{0}".format(index)
class FunkyBackwards():
    def __reversed__(self):
        return "BACKWARDS!"

for seq in normal_list, CustomSequence(), FunkyBackwards():
    print("\n{}: ".format(seq.__class__.__name__), end="")
    for item in reversed(seq):
        print(item, end=", ")
```

I understand that customizing `__len__` will make all objects with type CustomeSequence will return a length of 5, and the index of something with length 5 will return `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, at least to my understanding. My question is, why does `__getitem__.index` look for `__len__`?

The function prints this:

```
list: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
CustomSequence: x4, x3, x2, x1, x0, 
FunkyBackwards: B, A, C, K, W, A, R, D, S, !,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__):

> If the `__reversed__()` method is not provided, the `reversed()`
>   built-in will fall back to using the sequence protocol (`__len__()`
>   and `__getitem__())`.

Answer (score 2):

No, `__getitem__` does not "look for" `len`. It's simply that in order to reverse a sequence you must know its last item, and for that you need the length of the sequence, or the `__reversed__` magic method.

So, Python's `reversed` first finds the length of the sequence and retrieves its elements starting from the last one:

```
def python_reverse(data):
    for x in range(data.__len__() - 1, -1, -1):
        yield data.__getitem__(x)
```

(It's not Pythonic to call magic methods explicitly. These calls are here just to show their usage. In real code please use `len` and the index notation `data[x]` instead).